# How to __repr__ type unicode from database model

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, unicode, flask-sqlalchemy

Working with Python 2.7.4 and flask-sqlalchemy on Win 7.

In my database I have for example model named `šaš šuđa`, how would I display in name with `__repr__` in this current model.

```
class Car(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cars'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    county = db.Column(db.String(64))
    model = db.Column(db.UnicodeText(64))


def __repr__(self):
    return 'Country: %s  Model: %s' % (self.country, self.model)
```

I have try using `u"{0}".format(self.model)` with same result.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0111' in position 105: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2, `__repr__` **must** return a byte string; Python will try to encode it for you if you do not.

Encode your values explicitly:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return 'Country: %s  Model: %s' % (
        self.country.encode('utf8'), self.model.encode('utf8'))
```

If you wanted to return unicode values in combination with Jinja2, you can define a `__unicode__` method instead:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'Country: %s  Model: %s' % (self.country, self.model)
```

Comment: This is what I get now: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 53: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @Ecce_Homo: are you mixing the `__repr__` output with other Unicode strings somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, I am looping in jinja2 templating language and displaying every Country and Model  with |safe.

Comment: @Ecce_Homo: Then don't use `__repr__`; create a new method that returns a Unicode string instead.